# Finding features based on percentage overlap of another feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, overlapping-features, overlay

I have a feature class of 'Firezone' polygons. I have a feature class of 'Area ID"
The Area ID features are smaller than and overlap the Firezones.
I wish to find all of the Area ID features that overlap any Firezone feature by more than 50 percent of itself.

The Firezones are in red; AreaIDs in blue.

I have tried various runs of within, contain, within Clementini, contain Clementini

[image]

Comment: Have you explored using the [Polygon Neighbours](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/polygon-neighbors.htm) tool?

Answer (score 0):

Intersect input layers:

[image]

Summarize resulting shape areas by AREA_ID identifier and join output to AREA_ID table. Compute percentage of original area:

[image]